# Which is better for selecting among these 1.sys_refcursor 2. custom JSON 3.custom object/record type from Oracle 12c plsql procedure, Java 8?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, cursor, sys-refcursor

I want to fetch data from Oracle 12c database PL/SQL using Select operation.
I have 3 options to return data. 
1. Using Sys_RefCursor

Oralce Part

```
Procedure Get_Data(
  o_Cursor In Out SYS_REFCURSOR,
  i_Row_Id In Number
  )
Is 
Begin
   Open o_Cursor For
    Select * From My_Table Where Row_Id = i_Row_Id;         
End;
```

Java Part

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call My_Package_Name.Get_Data(?,?)}");
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cs.setInt(2, data.get("row_id").getAsInt());
            cs.execute();
            rs = (ResultSet)cs.getObject(1);
```

But, in this case, I don't know Oracle Procedure itself closing the Cursor implicitly or not.

When I use

```
Close o_cursor
```

at the end of procedure it is not giving me desired result.

2. Using Custom Apex Json since I used Oracle 12c it supports Json format so 
   I can return my resultSet row using custom Json

   `Select * Into rt From My_Table t Where t.Row_Id = 1;
             json.Push('row_id', rt.Row_Id);
             json.Push('row_name', rt.Row_Name);
             Return json.to_string();`

And reading it as string in Java

3. Can I use

   `TYPE CUSTOMER_REC IS RECORD
      (
         CUST_NO     NUMBER,
         CUST_CODE   VARCHAR2 (50),
         CUST_NAME   VARCHAR2 (500)
      );`

Returning my select resultSet as CUSTOMER_REC format and in 
Java read it as

```
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "typeName");
```

Can someone give detailed explanation about each part and which is better to use (performance perspective) and which is old approach in this case ? and Is Sys_RefCursor closed implicitly by Oracle Environment?

Comment: `Sys_refcursors` are best suited for web based applications since it doesnot require explicit close. Once the data is fected and session is disconnected, cache is cleared.

Comment: Option 4: Run `SELECT` statement from Java.

Comment: I have several types of Select statements based on the condition I will choose one of them. in this case, Is writing Select in Java with several if else conditions good practice or not, I am not sure. Therefore, I wanted to move logic to database part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your can see for yourself in the code for option 1, the `SYS_REFCURSOR` maps to a `ResultSet` in Java, so the cursor is closed when you close the `ResultSet`.

Note that `ResultSet` objects are automatically closed when the `Statement` is closed, or when the `Statement` executes another SQL statement, and that the `Statement` is closed when the `Connection` is closed.

Even for pooled connections, where calling `connection.close()` returns the connection to the pool, so the physical connection remains open, the call to `close()` still closes all `Statement` objects on the `Connection`, and hence closes all `ResultSet` objects too.

If your code runs for a while after using a `ResultSet`, and especially if your code executes a loop to process multiple `ResultSet` objects, you should always close the `ResultSet` objects as soon as you're done with them, preferably using *try-with-resources*.

If connection is closed soon after using a `ResultSet` object, you can rely on the connection closing the `ResultSet` objects for you. If you're not sure, then close them yourself.

As for your question, option 1 is best. Option 2 would be much slower, and option 3 is more work.

Comment: I accepted your answer it is clear enough. But One thing to ask, Is Sys_Refcursors or Cursors are reliable enough. I don't have too much experience in Oracle so, don't know too much about cursors' all supported cases.

Comment: @RahimjonRustamov They are a core part of Oracle's Database. Why wouldn't they be reliable?

Comment: Great! @Andreas I wanted to make sure because I am going to use this code for sensitive data and transactions.